# Fortran and Eclipse: Displaying text in console

Tags: eclipse, text, console, fortran

I'm having a small difficulty with Fortran 90 and Eclipse. I installed the "Photran" plugin to Eclipse, and have managed to compile everything perfect, and overall the program does what it has to do. The problem comes when displaying text in the Eclipse console. The code it self not that important, since it does what it has to do, but more the output generation.

The piece of the code I'm having trouble with is the following:

```
subroutine main_program

   write(*,*) "Program begins!"

   <Program that takes ~5mins to run>

   write(*,*) "Program ends!"

end subroutine main_program
```

Specifically, the problem is that in the console, the first message should be shown immediately, "Program begins!", and after ~5 minutes it should show "Program ends!". It happens that both of these messages get displayed only after the program is done running, not while the programs is executing.

I have used:

```
subroutine main_program

   print*, "Program begins!"

   <Program that takes ~5mins to run>

   print*, "Program ends!"

end subroutine main_program
```

but it keeps on doing the same thing. I saw a "similar" post earlier (can't find the link though, sorry about that) but it was not really what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much! After like 2 years of searching I was finally brave enough to ask such a silly question. Thanks and kudos to you sir.

Comment: So did it help? It would be helpful to specify your operating system and compiler.

Comment: it did help and it worked. I'm using GCC Fortran, Windows 7 (64bit), Intel i7. Hope this helps or if you need more info, I can give it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's the answer.   Insert the statement

```
flush 6
```

after the first `write` statement to have its output sent immediately to the console.  Insert it anywhere else you wish once you understand what it is doing.

It is obvious (to me) from the situation OP describes that the output is being buffered, that is the program issues a `write` statement and passes the output off to the operating system which does as it damn well pleases -- here it waits until  the program ends before writing anything to the console.  I guess that its buffering capabilities have some limits and if the program exceeded them the o/s would empty its buffers prior to program end.

Fortran now (since 2003 I think) provides a standard way of telling the o/s to actually flush the buffer to the output device -- the `flush` statement.  In its simplest form `flush` takes only one argument, the unit number of the output channel to be flushed.  I guessed that OP had unit 6 connected to `stdout` (aka `*`), since this is a near-universal default configuration, though not one guaranteed by the Fortran language standard.

I don't think that `flush *` is correct.

If you have a pre-2003 compiler then (a) for Backus' sake update and (b) it is likely that it supports a non-standard way to flush buffers; if memory serves `gfortran` used to provide a subroutine which would be called something like `call flush(6)`.

There are other ways, outside Fortran, to tell the o/s to write to disk (or console or what have you) immediately.  Look at the documentation for your o/s if you are interested in them.